# unit of fft(DFT) x axis

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, dft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Frequency from FFT result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result)

I am somehow confused with the x axis of fft(DFT) command in Matlab. When we do a fft command for a signal which has sampled in n point, we get a plot in which the x axis is 0 to n-1. Does it mean frequency in Hz? For example when I have a spike on n=2 is it mean that the signal frequency is 2Hz?

Comment: May also find this useful (Units of a Fourier Transform (FFT) when doing Spectral Analysis of a Signal) http://stackoverflow.com/q/1523814/181638

Answer (score 13):

The X axis is dimensionless. To get the correspondence between bin index and frequency you need to know (a) the sample rate (in Hz), `Fs`, and (b) the number of points in the FFT, `N`. The centre frequency for the bin is then:

```
f = i * Fs / N
```

where `f` is the bin frequency in Hz and `i` is the bin index.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result/4371627#4371627) for a more complete explanation.