# What is the unit of Y axis from frequency spectrum using RealDoubleFFT class?

Tags: android, audio, fft

I'm making an apps that shows spectrum frequency for its features using RealDoubleFFT class from jfftpack. But, I haven't put the scale and unit for the Y axis yet (I've only put scale and unit in X axis that is frequency).
What is actually the unit of Y axis (based on the RealDoubleFFT class)? Can anyone help me?

Comment: The y-axis is the amplitude of the signal.

Comment: Amplitude in what unit? dB, volts, or something else?

Comment: In PCM sample values.  Which (you hope) have a linear relationship to signal voltage. Signal power in dBFS will be `20log10(V/VMax)`

Comment: I've thinking like that too, but based on the output spektrum by method toTransform[0][i], the output value is between -10 to 10 and i have no idea whats the unit of this value. If i know the unit, i can convert it into other units like db or kind of that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Units of a Fourier Transform (FFT) when doing Spectral Analysis of a Signal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523814/units-of-a-fourier-transform-fft-when-doing-spectral-analysis-of-a-signal)